# "water.exceptions.H2ONotFoundArgumentException" failing to find schema for MOJO models

Tags: java, h2o

I am trying to export a trained model as a MOJO, but when I run:

```
aml.leader().getMojo().writeTo(os);
```

I get

```
water.exceptions.H2ONotFoundArgumentException
water.api.SchemaServer.schema(SchemaServer.java:281)
Failed to find schema for version: 3 and type: GLMModel
```

I am running H2O for a Java project, so after starting the H2OApp, I also registered the schemas.